# Spring RequestMappingHandlerMapping Startup Slow

Tags: java, spring

I am using [this Github tool](https://github.com/lwaddicor/spring-startup-analysis) to analyze my Spring Boot application start up time. Here's a screenshot of the analysis results:

[image]

I am not sure how accurate the results are because the tool says the start up time was 41 seconds but my IDE console says it took 98 seconds.

But regardless of the accuracy the largest block is `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping`

Why is this spring component so slow and how I can I best optimize the startup time.

Answer (score 1):

please share more info what you are doing in initialization phase...but RequestMappingHandlerMapping Creates RequestMappingInfo instances from type and method-level @RequestMapping annotations in @Controller classes.

Comment: what info exactly?